# Reading a text file with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have tens of thousands of text files to analyze, where each text file represents a snapshot in time of the physical state of a system. The micro-state of each "pixel" is represented by floats from 0 to 1. **Is it possible for OpenCV to directly read a text file without first having to convert the text file to an image format?** I do not want to create tens of thousands of image files every time I carry out this analysis.

**Context/goal:** I am analyzing a thermal simulation of a nano-magnetic system, and will eventually need to use OpenCV to calculate the contour areas of clusters formed above a certain threshold value.

I've included my code attempt below, using a test text file. The system is a square system of side length 40, and I am analyzing the column of 40^2 = 1600 data points which I call *mag* (for magnetization, as this is from a scientific research project). I multiply each "pixel" by 255 to mimic grayscale. As soon as the program reaches the cv2.threshold line, I get an error:

> ~/anaconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.8/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:783: error: (-210) in function threshold

which I suspect arises from my mimicking grayscale instead of reading an actual grayscale image file.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
SideDim = 40

dud, mag = np.loadtxt('Aex_testfile.txt', unpack=True, usecols=(4,5), skiprows=2)

mag = np.reshape(mag, (SideDim,SideDim))

for row in range(SideDim):
    for col in range(SideDim):
        mag[row][col] = round(255 * mag[row][col])
mag = mag.astype(np.int)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mag,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(thresh,'gray')
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need opencv for this. I don't know opencv but your threshold signature doesn't match `Python: cv.Threshold(src, dst, threshold, maxValue, thresholdType) → None` found [in the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv.Threshold). What do you want the array to be? 0 for < .5 and 1 >= .5? That's easy with `numpy`.

Comment: Questions are easier to answer if they have runnable examples. Would `mag = np.arange(0, 1, 1./(40*40)).reshape((40,40))` be a fair representation of your data for test?

Comment: Have a look at OpenCV FileStorage class. It lets you load a Mat to a file and vice versa. I'm not sure if it's supported in python, but it works in C++

Comment: @tdelaney, I haven't told the entire story here for why I need OpenCV, but I should have mentioned it. I will eventually need to calculate the contour areas (cv2.contourarea) for "blobs" above a certain threshold later on, which is why it's imperative I get this problem compatible with OpenCV. Should I update my question?

Comment: @tdelaney, your proposed 2D array is adequate for the purpose of this question, but would not be a fair representation of my data (I understand because I didn't tell you what my goals are until now). The system I am analyzing forms clusters ("blobs") of value 1 (or close to) in different regions of the 40x40 matrix over time. In fact, it is a thermal simulation of a nano-magnetic system. My goal is to calculate the average area of clusters formed above a certain threshold, over time. Hopefully that gives you all the contextual information you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Regarding the question in your post title:

In Python, CV2 does not convert text into an image format. Instead, "images" are just numpy arrays. You are then correct in using `np.loadtxt` to import data (though I'm partial to `np.genfromtxt()`, as it's slightly more robust).

## Regarding the error you're getting:

Error code -210 is defined as:

> #define CV_StsUnsupportedFormat -210 /* the data format/type is not supported by the function*/

`cv2.threshold()` uses an 8 bit integer. Instead of casting mag as `np.int`, cast it as `np.uint8`. This should fix your error

## Other things to note:

With numpy arrays, you don't need to use those ugly nested loops to multiply each value by 255. Instead, just do `mag * 255`.

Instead of multiplying by 255 (which doesn't quite make sense unless you're positive your maximum value is 1...), you should really just normalize your array. Something like `(mag / mag.amax()) * 255` would be a better solution.

You don't need open CV for this part of the program. Instead, you can just do it in numpy:

```
thresh = 255 * (mag > threshval)
```

this will produce an array (thresh) that has any values greater than threshval set equal to 255

In general, I think it would behoove you to learn numpy before jumping into opencv. I think you'd be surprised at how much you can do in numpy.